# How to pass checkbox values that are created by the user to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, pug

I have an input form, where users create their own "cards". The data goes to PostgreSQL database and I render the results on a page (see below). After creating the cards, I want them to be able to select the ones they like and display only these selected cards on the next page (/play).

[image: Customized cards]

My code (I use pug):

```
div(id="all-cards")
    div(class='card')
        each card in cards
            p Title: #{card.title}
            p Question: #{card.question}
            p Subquestion: #{card.subquestion}
            p Task: #{card.task}

            form(name="selection" action="" method="post")
                input(type="checkbox" value="card" title="Select" name="option") 
                label Select
                button(type="submit" name="select" class="select-cards") Select The Cards
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pug, but it seems you have a form for each card, that implies you only can select one card at time. I should recommend you to use only one form and use an attribute "name" for each card.

```
div(id="all-cards")
    div(class='card')
      form(name="selection" action="" method="post")
        each card in cards
            p Title: #{card.title}
            p Question: #{card.question}
            p Subquestion: #{card.subquestion}
            p Task: #{card.task}

            input(type="checkbox" value="1" title="Select" name="#{card.id}") 
            label Select
```

Then, when the form is submitte you will have an array:

```
 $_POST['id1' => 1,... idn => 1]
```

corresponding with the previous selection and you can deal with it:

```
foreach($_POST = $key => $value){
  $selected[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with php, I work with Node js. Would it be something like this in Node.js:     app.post('/cards', function(req,res) {
     var card = card.id
 
     Card.findAll({
      where: {
       id: card.id
      }
     })
     .then(function(){
      res.redirect('/play')
     })
    })

Comment: Also, I forgot to add the submit button for the checkbox, added it to my code.

Comment: The issue is in your html, use one form and then, when you retrieve the data from the request object you can include it in your redirection.

Comment: I took the code that you suggested but now I have the issue in my Node.js as the post request is wrong..." Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: input(type="checkbox" value="#{card.id}" title="Select" name="#{card.id}") why? when you submit the http request will create a variable for each element checked ("name"="value"&...) so you have to focus in your "names". Once you get the query object (after parsing, i.e: (url.parse(req.url).query

Answer (score 0):

Make the `form` a wrapper for all the cards. Change the `name` of the `checkbox`es to something like `cards[]` and change the value for each card(put the ID or something distinctive) . When you submit the forms you will get an array of cards. The `cards` param will be filled with the id's of the selected cards.